# How to read header of Multiple dicom files in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Please can anyone tell me a method to read header of multiple dicom(mri) images 
and store them in a structure

i really need to do this in my project

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading the [Statistical Parametric Mapping (SPM) software package](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/) for MATLAB. The newest version is [SPM8](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/software/spm8/), and we use it often for our fMRI data processing.

After downloading, unzipping, and adding the package to your MATLAB path, you can use the function `spm_dicom_headers` to read just the header information from your DICOM files. You can call the function like so:

```
hdr = spm_dicom_headers(fileArray);
```

Where `fileArray` is a [character array of strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strings.html) with one file name/path per row, and `hdr` is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) of header information (one cell per file).